# Cosmos db joins give duplicate results

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Given a document strukture like this:

```
{
  Id: "1",
  Title:"One",
  Children: [
    {Id:"A", Date:"01-01-2015"},
    {Id:"B", Date:"01-01-2016"},
  ]
}
```

I want to get all documents that has a child date later than "01-01-2014". The query I've tried is:

```
SELECT parent.id, parent.Title
FROM parent 
JOIN child IN parent.Children
child.Date >= "01-01-2014"
```

This will give a duplicate result. Is there any way to write this query so that it will only return distinct parents?

Answer (score 4):

Why don't just use `distinct` keyword in sql to eliminate duplicate records? It's supported by cosmos db.

```
SELECT distinct parent.id, parent.Title
FROM parent 
JOIN child IN parent.Children
where child.Date >= "01-01-2014"
```

[image]

Hope it helps you.

---

Update Answer:

I tested `SqlQuerySpec` in java sdk and it works fine.

```
        String collectionLink = String.format("/dbs/%s/colls/%s", "db", "coll");

        SqlQuerySpec sqlQuerySpec = new SqlQuerySpec();
        sqlQuerySpec.setQueryText("select distinct c.name from c");

        FeedResponse<Document> queryResults = documentClient.queryDocuments(
                collectionLink,
                sqlQuerySpec, queryOptions);

        System.out.println("Running SQL query...");
        for (Document document : queryResults.getQueryIterable()) {
            System.out.println(String.format("\tRead %s", document)); 
        }
```

My Sdk version is :`1.16.2`(latest)

Comment: If the intention is to filter by documents that has a child date later than a certain date, then using EXISTS with a subquery is more efficient than opting for a JOIN and then using DISTINCT to remove duplicates.

Comment: When I run this in the portal query explorer it works fine. But as with "Exists" it seems like the sdk has no support for it and it gives me an exception.

Comment: @Zaphod Hi, I think no need to use Exists.Just use distinct with your question.Any further requirements about your situation so that distinct is useless?Just let me know.Thank you.

Comment: I'm not using Exists when trying distinct. It just gives the same result as when I try Exits. None of them work. I use a SqlQuerySpec object, your query (with only distinct) and it gives an exception. It works fine in the query explorer but not in code..

Comment: @Zaphod Hi,please see my update answer. I tested in java sdk and it works fine. Any difference between us.Have you tried latest sdk on your side?

Comment: @JayGong Can you please try the SqlQuerySpec query with a join? I think it might be an issue only when you use join and distinct. I will test again.

Comment: @Zaphod I tested with join,still could get the correct result.Any updates on your side?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178426/discussion-between-jay-gong-and-zaphod).

Answer (score 2):

You could use EXISTS expression to perform the comparison of the array items in a subquery.
Try this query:

```
SELECT parent.id, parent.Title
FROM parent
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT VALUE child FROM child IN parent.Children WHERE child.Date >= "01-01-2014")
```

Comment: When I run this in the query explorer in the azure portal it seems to work fine. But when I do it with code (ie using a SqlQuerySpec) I get a "The method or operation is not implemented." on "Windows/6.3.9600 documentdb-netcore-sdk/1.9.1". Is "Exists" not in the 1.9.1 sdk?

Answer (score 1):

Basically the duplicating records is the **expected** behaviour in the projection above, because for the join all conditions are met per parent + children[0] and parent + children[1].

If you need to retrieve only unique one you have to use [ARRAY_CONTAINS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-sql-query-reference#bk_array_contains) over the `Childrens` list.

However, there are no way to provide condition for the array items, so you have to hardcode ( I know it's not ideal and shall be used only as the last resort) date value and use partial match ( set last param to true):

```
SELECT parent.id, parent.Title
FROM parent WHERE
    ARRAY_CONTAINS(parent.Childred, {"Date": "2014"}, true) OR 
    ARRAY_CONTAINS(parent.Childred, {"Date": "2015"}, true) OR
    ARRAY_CONTAINS(parent.Childred, {"Date": "2016"}, true) OR 
    ARRAY_CONTAINS(parent.Childred, {"Date": "2017"}, true) OR 
    ARRAY_CONTAINS(parent.Childred, {"Date": "2018"}, true)
```

Comment: I know it's expected behaviour, I just can't find the right way of doing it. ARRAY_CONTAINS doesn't allow for "greater than" comparisons as far as I've seen. Do you have an example query that would give the right annswer?

Comment: Thanks, but this is not good enough. The query date might be 06-06-2015 and then I'd need to make too many ARRAY_CONTAINS statements. Seems like the only way to achieve this is by doing the distinct filtering in code. Not what I was hoping for, but seems to be the only way.